# AngularJS : After ng-repeat $scope values not updated as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a controller that contains data to be iterated over with an ng-repeat, and I'm using it alongside [this selection model directive](https://github.com/jtrussell/angular-selection-model).

After using ng-repeat to create several entries in the DOM, the bindings to $scope.selectedItems stop working.

I know ng-repeat create a new child scope for each iteration, but shouldn't the updates to the selectedItems property still be picked up by binding to values in the MyController?

Controller:

```
(function() {
    angular.module('myModule', ['product.module'])
        .controller('MyController' ['$scope', 'SomeService' function($scope, ProductService) {
            $scope.selectedItems = [];
            $scope.productService = new ProductService()  //constructor pattern object
            $scope.products = $scope.productService.items;

            $scope.productService.fetchData(); //grabs data from server and sets the productService.items to an array of objects                
        }]);
})();
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="product in products"
        selection-model-type="checkbox"
        selection-model-mode="multiple"
        selection-model-selected-items="selectedItems">
        {{product.name}}
    </li>
</ul>


<div ng-controller="MyController"> <!-- this binding doesn't work after the ng-repeat takes place -->
    There are {{selectedItems.length}} products
</div>
```

Comment: One possible problem I can see is `fetchData`, if that method is doing something like `items = <new-array>` then it won't work because your `$scope.products` will still be referring to the old array

Comment: try to change `ng-repeat="product in products"` to `ng-repeat="product in productService.items"`

Comment: you have two instance of  `Mycontroller`. `{{selectedItem.length}}` will not have the selected items that you selected in ng-repeat..

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks for the response, but the code inside the product instance only alters the array, and never creates a new one.  Just want to be sure future readers of this question understand that also.

Answer (score 0):

`productService.items` may refer to the same instance all the time but `selectedItems` surely not. Use only one controller or place `selectedItems` into a service.

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="product in products"
        selection-model-type="checkbox"
        selection-model-mode="multiple"
        selection-model-selected-items="selectedItems">
        {{product.name}}
    </li>
</ul>

    There are {{selectedItems.length}} products
</div>
```